# A Shell script that can be executed by just typing its name

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a shell script that takes one variable as an argument, the way I execute it now is by typing `bash script.sh arg1`, is it possible to trigger it by just typing `script arg1`? thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to start your script with line:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

and make its file executable: `chmod +x script.sh`. Then you could run it by typing `./script.sh` or even by just `script.sh` if it is located in one of the paths from your PATH environment variable.

Note that the filename does not matter. It could be `script.sh`, `script` or whatever you want.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how to obtain `./script arg1`:

- ensure that the first line of your script is `#!/bin/bash`;
- rename it to `script`;
- go to the directory where the script resides and type the above.

If you want to type `script arg1` directly:

- ensure that you have `$HOME/bin` in your path;
- type `install -D -m700 /path/to/script $HOME/bin/script`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you rename it to script, set the executable bit, use the correct shebang line, and put the folder it is located it, into your $PATH:

```
mv script.sh script
chmod u+x script
make sure the first line in the script is #!/bin/bash (or the correct interpreter if it's not bash)
PATH=${PATH}:/path/to/script
```

After that, you can run it just by typing "script arg1".

$PATH is a list of folders, seperated by a :, that the shell looks in, when you execute something without specifying a path. You will need to put that line (the last line) into your .bashrc, (or the file that your shell reads at login, if you are not using bash) to make it permanent.

Answer (score 0):

Place the script in your `/usr/local/bin` and make sure that path is added to your `$PATH` variable.